# How to write a mongodb query when keys are all different

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongodb collection which has bunch of documents. Each document will be in the following format

```
{ 
    "_id" : "xyz", 
    "t_1" : {
        "start" : "2018-07-18 04:12:00+00:00", 
        "duration" : "0 days 00:06:28", 
        "A": 10
     },
    "t_2" : {
        "start" : "2018-07-24 07:15:00+00:00", 
        "duration" : "0 days 00:06:28", 
        "B": 20
     },
...
}
```

How should I write a query to find

1. `t`s (`t_1`, `t_2` etc. ) for a given `_id` that have `B` greater than 10
2. find start of `t`s which have `B`  greater than 10 for a given `_id`
3. find `_id`s of documents which have at least one `B` in the `t`s

Please note it is not mandatory that all `t`s have `B` key. Some of them may not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get around this is to run an aggregate pipeline that gets data about the keys at the root level of the document,
denoted by the system variable [`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT), run through their values and determine whether they have more than one key.

For the first step, use [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) add an extra field that holds the above computations and use [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to convert 
the key/value pairs to an array of `[ { k: 'key name': v: 'value' }, ... ]`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { '$addFields': {
        'fields': { '$objectToArray': '$$ROOT' }
    } }
])
```

On getting this array, the next step will be to filter the list

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    # convert dynamic fields to key/value arrays
    { '$addFields': {
        'fields': { '$objectToArray': '$$ROOT' }
    } },

    # filter where B > 10
    { '$addFields': {
        'fields': {
            '$filter': {
                'input': '$fields',
                'cond': {
                    '$and': [
                        { '$ne':  [ { '$type' : "$$this.v.B" }, 'missing'] },
                        { '$gt': [ "$$this.v.B", 10 ] }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    } }
])
```

The pipelines for the required queries then follow:

1.`t`s (`t_1`, `t_2` etc. ) for a given `_id` that have `B` greater than 10

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { '$addFields': {
        'fields': {
            '$filter': {
                'input': { '$objectToArray': '$$ROOT' },
                'cond': {
                    '$and': [
                        { '$ne':  [ { '$type' : "$$this.v.B" }, 'missing'] },
                        { '$gt': [ "$$this.v.B", 10 ] }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    } },
    { '$addFields': {
        't_s': '$fields.k' 
    } }
])
```

2.find start of `t`s which have `B`  greater than 10 for a given `_id`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { '$match': { '_id': "xyz" } },
    { '$addFields': {
        'fields': {
            '$filter': {
                'input': '$fields',
                'cond': {
                    '$and': [
                        { '$ne':  [ { '$type' : "$$this.v.B" }, 'missing'] },
                        { '$gt': [ "$$this.v.B", 10 ] }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    } },
    { '$addFields': {
        'start_times': '$fields.v.start' 
    } }
])
```

3.find _ids of documents which have at least one B in the ts

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    # convert root dynamic fields to key/value pair array
    { '$addFields': {
        'fields': { '$objectToArray': '$$ROOT' }
    } },


    # filter all documents where size of array of Bs >= 1
    { '$match': {
        '$expr': {
            '$gte': [
                { '$size': '$fields.v.B' },
                1
            ]
        }
    } },


    # get array of _ids
    { '$addFields': {
        'ids': {
            '$filter': {
                'input': '$fields',
                'cond': { '$eq': [ '$$this.k', '_id' ] }
            }
        }
    } },

    # reshape field
    { '$addFields': {
        'ids': '$ids.v'
    } }
])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. I could find a way to implement it based on your answer :)